# Inputs in different line because label size is different

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to put my input in same line in Bootstrap v3, but they are staying in different line Because the size of their labels

```
<div class="row">

                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label for="precisaAnalista">Você precisa um analista para ajudá-lo na gestão de suas campanhas?</label>
                        <select name="precisaAnalista" id="precisaAnalista" class="form-control">
                            <option selected style="display:none;" value="">Selecione uma resposta</option>
                            <option value="true">Sim</option>
                            <option value="false">Não</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label for="precisaCapital">Você precisa de capital para escalar suas campanhas?</label>
                        <select name="precisaCapital" onchange="precisaCap(this.value);" id="precisaCapital" class="form-control">
                            <option selected style="display:none;" value="">Selecione uma resposta</option>
                            <option value="true">Sim</option>
                            <option value="false">Não</option>
                        </select>
                        <input style="display:none;" type="number" min="0" name="qtdCapital" value="" id="qtdCapital" placeholder="Quantos?" class="form-control">
                    </div>

 </div>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLHwf.png)

Comment: Please add your code, and what you tried, to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a min-height attribute on the label tag:

> min-height:40px;